# compare dataframes and mark matches in r

Tags: r, dataframe

I am very new to R. I am trying to compare two csv files:
csv 1:

```html
<table id="t01">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Email</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>evejackson@yahoo.co.uk</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Jon</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>johnsmith@gmail.com</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

csv2:

```html
<table id="t02">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Email</th>
  </tr>
  
    <tr>
    <td>Jon</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>johnsmith@gmail.com</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Samantha</td>
    <td>Andrew</td> 
    <td>samanthaandrew@yahoo.co.uk</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

What I want is to have a code that compares "Email" between the two tables, and then enters "registered" on a 4th column in csv 1, where there is a match. Like this:

```html
<table id="t03">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Status</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>evejackson@yahoo.co.uk</td>
    
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Jon</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>johnsmith@gmail.com</td>
    <td> Registered</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If there is no match, then the code should compare firstname + lastname between the two tables, and enter "registered" if there is a match. I have no idea how to do this in R, even though it might be quite straightforward. Thank you.

Comment: You can do a `merge using `Firstname` and `Lastname`

Comment: Thanks, but I'm trying to compare emails first, and only move on to the firstname and lastname if there is no match with emails. Very new to R, so unsure how to write it.

Comment: ok, then use emails also in the `by`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides the `merge` option proposed by @akrun, you can also use `ifelse()` statements. Here is an example:

```
df1 <- data.frame(Firstname = c("Eve", "Jon", "Steve"), 
                  Lastname = c("Jackson", "Smith", "Jackson"),
                  Email = c("evejackson@yahoo.co.uk", "johnsmith@gmail.com",
                            "stevejackson@yahoo.com"),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
# df1
      Firstname Lastname                  Email
1       Eve  Jackson evejackson@yahoo.co.uk
2       Jon    Smith    johnsmith@gmail.com
3     Steve  Jackson stevejackson@yahoo.com

df2 <- data.frame(Firstname = c("Jon", "Samantha", "Steve"), 
                  Lastname = c('Smith', "Andrew", "Jackson"),
                  Email = c("johnsmith@gmail.com", "samanthaandrew@yahoo.co.uk",
                            "stevejackson@yahoo.co.uk"),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
# df2
  Firstname Lastname                      Email
1       Jon    Smith        johnsmith@gmail.com
2  Samantha   Andrew samanthaandrew@yahoo.co.uk
3     Steve  Jackson   stevejackson@yahoo.co.uk

# check if Emails in df1 are also in df2 and then if Firstname and Lastname are the
# same in df1 and df2 
df1$Status <- ifelse(df1$Email %in% df2$Email, "Registered",
                     ifelse(df1$Firstname == df2$Firstname &
                                    df1$Lastname == df2$Lastname, "Registered",
                            ""))
df1 # output
  Firstname Lastname                  Email     Status
1       Eve  Jackson evejackson@yahoo.co.uk           
2       Jon    Smith    johnsmith@gmail.com Registered
3     Steve  Jackson stevejackson@yahoo.com Registered
```

Comment: I have tried this out and it's great. Just a quick question, completely based on how little my R knowledge is, my spreadsheet, which will be the dataframe in this case has quite a number of roles, so I won't be building the vectors with "c". How should I implement the stringsAsFactors = FALSE on a full column?

Comment: Use `df$column <- as.character(df$column)` after importing you data in R. During the import, you can also use the argument `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` to set strings as characters instead of factors. See [this](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/read.table.html)

Comment: Thank you. It does answer my question. I will try this out and post the final code. I have tried to "upvote" it, but as I haven't used stackoverflow that much, I don't have enough "reputation" :)

Comment: Perfect! You don't need reputation to accept (not upvote) an answer. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) is a good starting point. Also, you don't have to post your final code

Comment: I've tried this out with my data, and I keep getting this error 

"Warning messages:
1: In df1$firstname_gmail == df2$firstname :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length"

I have a feeling it might be that some firstnames are two names. Just wondering how to circumvent this?

Comment: `df1$firstname_gmail == df2$firstname` would work fine only if both vectors have the same length and are sorted in the same order as in your example

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using `df1$firstname_gmail %in% df2$firstname` and it worked. The two vectors could not be the same because the number of elements was different.